# C - sizeof() on static char arrays inside a struct - impossible?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, sizeof

I need to store two items per array element — two arrays of `char`, which might contain null bytes — and then still be able to use `sizeof()` to get their length.  Since these values will not change during execution, I think GCC should be able to handle this.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct name_data {
    char *name;
    char *data;
} name_bins [] = {
    { "John", "\xAA\xAA\x00\xAA" },
    { "Mark", "\xFF\x0A\x00\x33\x01\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05" },
};

char bin_test[] = "\xFF\x0A\x00\x33\x01\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05";

int main () {
    printf("sizeof(bin_test) = %lu\n", sizeof(bin_test));
    printf("sizeof(name_bins[1].data) = %lu\n", sizeof(name_bins[1].data));
    exit(0);
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
sizeof(bin_test) = 11
sizeof(name_bins[1].data) = 8
```

However, `bin_test` is equivalent to `name_bins[1].data` in content — although the type definition is different — `bin_test` is a `char[]` and `names_bins[1].data` is a `char*`.

Is there a way to define the `name_bins` array with `char[]`s instead?
Is there a way to force GCC to recognize this values as static constants and return the real content size with `sizeof()` — which it already calculates at compile time?

Comment: If your array of `char` might contain null bytes, consider defining it as an array of `uint8_t` for clarity.  Most C programmers consider `char *` to be a pointer to a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost do what you want by storing the size of `data` as a separate entry:

```
struct name_data {
    char  *name;
    char  *data;
    size_t data_size;
} name_bins[] = {
    {
        "John",
        "\xAA\xAA\x00\xAA",
        sizeof("\xAA\xAA\x00\xAA")
     }, {
         "Mark",
         "\xFF\x0A\x00\x33\x01\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05",
         sizeof("\xFF\x0A\x00\x33\x01\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05")
     }
};
```

And then:

```
printf("sizeof(bin_test) = %lu\n", sizeof(bin_test));
printf("sizeof(name_bins[1].data) = %lu\n", (unsigned long)name_bins[1].data_size);
```

Then you'd just have to make sure your `name_bins` initialization was right. You could toss a macro in the mix to avoid repeating yourself though:

```
#define BIN(x,y) { (x), (y), sizeof(y) }

struct name_data {
    char  *name;
    char  *data;
    size_t data_size;
} name_bins [] = {
    BIN("John", "\xAA\xAA\x00\xAA"),
    BIN("Mark", "\xFF\x0A\x00\x33\x01\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05")
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this! - is there a way to further optimize it so that I could use (sizeof([something pointing to the value above]) instead of having to re-paste the value?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible. The size of the `struct` is constant (`sizeof` any object `name_data` is always the same). If it were possible, you could have two objects of the same type, with different sizes.

Comment: Thanks cnicutar.  Is there another way I could define a struct array that keeps the logic of the above AND allows for the use of sizeof()?

Comment: @Arkadi I too would like to know of such a thing :)

Answer (score 1):

If you think for a bit about what you're asking the compiler to do here, you'll probably realize that what you're asking is not realistic.

In order for the compiler to figure out that `sizeof(name_bins[1].data)` is `11`, it would have to make sure that every possible path that leads to the line of code containing the `sizeof` has the exact same state when it comes to the `name_bins[1].data` object.

In the simple example you gave, you might expect the compiler to be able to somehow figure that out. But what if your application becomes more complex ? How will the compiler know that `name_bins[1].data` still contains `"\xFF\x0A\x00\x33\x01\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05"` ?

*EDIT* : Following up from the comments, you could create a new type that holds both the data and the size :

```
typedef struct ConstByteString {
    const unsigned char* data;
    size_t length;
} ConstByteString;
```

and then use that :

```
struct name_data {
    const char* name;
    ConstByteString data;
} name_bins [] = {
    { "John", { "\xAA\xAA\x00\xAA", sizeof("\xAA\xAA\x00\xAA") } },
    { "Mark", { "\xFF\x0A\x00\x33\x01\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05", sizeof("\xFF\x0A\x00\x33\x01\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05") } },
};
```

Comment: Thanks Sander - I do see your point, I was thinking that perhaps there is a way to tell GCC that this variable is untouchable (cannot change throughout the flow of execution) - and then, sizeof should be made possible.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @Arkadi : in short : no. Either `data` is a `char*`, and then `sizeof(name_bins[1].data)` will be the same as `sizeof(char*)`. Or `data` is an array of `char`, and then `sizeof(name_bins[1].data)` will return the total size of that array (but `sizeof(name_bins[i].data)` will be the same for every `i`). Why do you need this to work with `sizeof` ?

Comment: Because I cannot use strlen() since it might contain null bytes.  Is there a way to define the structure to contain 2 char[] instead of 2 char*, which WOULD allow for sizeof() to work? (I didn't managet to get this done)

Comment: @Arkadi : Why not store the size of the data with it in the struct ? Or better yet, create your own new type to abstract that detail (I'll add an example to the answer).

Comment: Thanks Sander, this is very similar to mu's answer - thanks for your help!

Comment: @Arkadi : that's true, I hadn't seen @mu's answer. I would still recommend creating the separate struct though, so that it's clear what the `length` field refers to.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion (along with mu's) and it works like a charm, thanks a lot.